# Как перезапустить surfaceView?

Tags: java, android, glsurfaceview

Я как понимаю после вызова `surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);` Запускается CallBack. И когда holder готов к работе, запускается surfaceCreated. Если я не прав поправьте плиз

---

Дело в том что у меня есть 2 камеры. 1 использую и после получения фотографии я должен закрыть SurfaceHolder. А после добавить его же в другую камеру.

Точнее это все происходит в CameraSource откуда я получаю камеру и т.д. Очень сложно объяснить, поэтому пишу сюда только основное.

Я читал много в документаации Гугл и не нашел что нужно было мне.
`surfaceView.getHolder().removeCallbacks` только отсоеденяет CallBack. Но не закрывает Holder. Помогите пожалуйста.

А то из - за этого я не могу логику приложения составить

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что "должен закрыть SurfaceHolder"? И как вы это себе представляете?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, Ну то что это некая поверхность для графики. После использования addCallback. Запускается метод surfaceCreatedв surface.

Вот вопрос в том как мне опять вызвать метод surfaceCreated....

Comment: Surface создается единожды. Вы либо создаете для каждой камеры свой surface, либо манипулируете им, проецируя то одну, то другую камеру.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, поэтому я и хочу перезапустить surface чтобы манипулировать камерами. Дело в том что Surface запускается сам по себе, не сразу. А может через сек. может через 5 сек... Вот я в методе `surfaceCreated` и запускаю камеру первую. 

А чтобы вторую камеру запустить мне надо выключить surface и затем заново его запустить, тоесть перезапустить чтобы метод `surfaceCreated` опять сработал.